# how to make getting average data by month more efficient

Tags: java, average

Hi I have two long blocks of code that I feel could be made way more efficient but I cant just seem to think of a way how.

Basically, I have a list of reports, I stepped through the list matching the recorded date to get all the reports of a certain year.

Next I created 12 lists for each month to separate the reports by month.

basically i step through each report of that year in the yearly list and check the characters for month and separate them like below-

```
for (int i = 0; i < yearlyReportList.size(); i++) {
        if (yearlyReportList.get(i).getDateTime().charAt(5) == '0' && yearlyReportList.get(i).getDateTime().charAt(6) == '1') {
            janReports.add(yearlyReportList.get(i));
        }
        if (yearlyReportList.get(i).getDateTime().charAt(5) == '0' && yearlyReportList.get(i).getDateTime().charAt(6) == '2') {
            febReports.add(yearlyReportList.get(i));
        }
        if (yearlyReportList.get(i).getDateTime().charAt(5) == '0' && yearlyReportList.get(i).getDateTime().charAt(6) == '3') {
            marchReports.add(yearlyReportList.get(i));
        }
....
```

next I average the data I need for each month like this- I pretty much copy and paste this 12 times and just change it each time for the month-

```
if (janReports.size() == 0) {
        avgJanData = 0;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < janReports.size(); i++) {
            janDataSum = janDataSum + janReports.get(i).getData();
        }

        avgJanData = janDataSum / janReports.size();
    }
....
```

but theres got to be a more efficient way then just copy pasting this code like this right?

can anyone give me an example how to make this code better?

help is appreciated.

Comment: Use nested if statements. The outermost would test only the condition `yearlyReportList.get(i).getDateTime().charAt(5) == '0'`. For the other block you could use `forEach` to loop through the monthly reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a method from you code snippet :

```
public float average(Collection<Report> reports) {

    for (int i = 0; i < janReports.size(); i++) {
        janDataSum = janDataSum + janReports.get(i).getData();
    }


    return janDataSum / janReports.size();
}
```

Then you call this method for each month.

Other solution if you are using Java 8 :

```
 janRepors.stream().mapToDouble(o -> o.getData()).average(); // this will return the average as a double.
```

Same : call it for each month.

***Global hint about your code :***
You could also use a Map using the month number as key to store your Reports instead of 12 variable, it should simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you get rid of ugly `yearlyReportList.get(i).getDateTime().charAt(5) == '0' && yearlyReportList.get(i).getDateTime().charAt(6) == '1'`

Lets get month number in int.

```
Integer.parseInt(yearlyReportList.get(i).getDateTime().substring(5, 6))
```

If you tell us format of date we can do it more "natural" way (by parsing date and extracting month).

Now lets fight with your copypast problem.

I suggest to make array and fill it in one pass

```
int[] sumsByMonth = new int[12];
int[] countsByMonth = new int[12];
for(Report report: yearlyReportList) {
     int month = Integer.parseInt(r.getDateTime().substring(5, 6));
     sumsByMonth[month - 1] += r.getData();
     countsByMonth[month - 1]++;
}
```

Arrays are filled with `0` by default.

All you have to do now is divide sum by count

```
double[] averagesByMonth = new double[12];
for(int i = 0; i<12; i++) {
    averagesByMonth[i] = ((double)sumsByMonth[i])/countsByMonth[i];
}
```

Cast to `double` required to switch from integer division to double division.

**Update**

You better use this to extract month:

```
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = format.parse(report.getDateTime());
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

In this case you get `0` based month number and there will be no need to subtract `1` while accessing array.

Comment: we have a date time that is stored as yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss... thanks

Comment: since we have our date times stored from 01 - 12 though, wouldnt we have to add them into the array like this --sumsByMonth[month - 1] += r.getData(); ? since in that case it would be added january at sumsByMonth[1] and december at sumsByMonth[12] which it doesnt have as sumsByMonth[11] is last one right?

Comment: @GarudaAiacos yes. I fix my answer.

Comment: I am having one more problem if you don't mind helping... that code is not working for the double digit months for some reason.. right now we only have reports from november ... which should be stored in spot [10] but it isnt for some reason its registering as [1] instead and going in the january spot.

Comment: It is something wrong with `substring` parameters. You can either tune them or use approach from update which is better anyway.